# Autofitting height for image with flexbox not working

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve the following solution with css flexbox:

[image: schematic overview]

I have create a Plunkr at https://plnkr.co/edit/TbJIdOrJLtDfczno4Kpu?p=preview which shows what I currently have.

- The `grid row` has a fixed height (class grid-row in Plunkr)
- The `red container` should autofit the height (article in Plunkr)
- The `header` and `footer` have a fixed height (header and footer in Plunkr)
- The image should autofit the remaining space and is set as a background image (Picture in Plunkr)

Whatever I try, the image does autofit the height of the grid-row. Does someone see what I am doing wrong?

**My HTML**

```
<div class="grid-row">

  <article>

    <header>
      Header text
    </header>

    <picture class="image">

    </picture>

    <footer>
      footer text
    </footer>

  </article>

</div>
```

**My CSS**

```
.grid-row {
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: auto;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Added the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you didn't extend the flexbox styling up/down through the structure.

```css
.grid-row {
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.image {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1; /* remaining height of article */
}
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1; /* 100% height of row */
}
header {
  background: red;
}
footer {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-row">

  <article>

    <header>
      Header text
    </header>

    <div class="image"></div>

    <footer>
      footer text
    </footer>

  </article>

</div>
```